# Send an (enter) to a runas command without user input

Tags: cmd

I have a need to perform a runas command, and send an enter keypress to the command without user interaction.

I understand that piping results out to a file, but i want to do it the other way, send n enter keypress to the command.

This is the command

```
runas.exe /user:XXX\USER_LOGIN notepad.exe
```

When this command is run, it prompts for a password...  i dont want to supply a password, just press the enter key.

FYI - this is a very simple user refresh, so it doesn't go stale when not used in a while.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try piping in a blank quoted string:

`echo "" | runas.exe /user:XXX\USER_LOGIN notepad.exe`

Comment: this sends two quotes and a space. To send just an "ENTER", use `echo/| runas ...`

Comment: Both solutions worked GREAT!! thank you both